# Substituting matrix for a scalar in SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

Here's what I'm doing in a SymPy session:

```
from sympy import *
xi1,xi2,xi3 = symbols('xi_1,xi_2,xi_3')
N1 = 1-xi1-xi2-xi3
N2 = xi3
N3 = xi1
N4 = xi2
x1,x2,x3,x4 = symbols('x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4')
x = N1*x1+N2*x2+N3*x3+N2*x4
subdict = {x1:Matrix([0.025,1.0,0.0]), x2 : Matrix([0,1,0]), x3:Matrix([0, 0.975, 0]), x4:Matrix([0,0.975,0.025])}
x.subs(subdict)
test.subs({xi1:1, xi2:0,xi3:0})
```

To me we are simply multiplying some scalars with some vectors then adding them up. However SymPy would disagree and throws a ginormous error for which the last line is:

```
TypeError: cannot add <class 'sympy.matrices.immutable.ImmutableDenseMatrix'> and <class 'sympy.core.numbers.Zero'>
```

Why is this a problem? Is there a workaround for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that what is happening is that before the matrix is substituted you substitute a 0 which makes `0*matrix_symbol = 0` instead of a matrix of zeros. Terms that end up being matrices cannot be added to 0 and thus the error. My attempts at using the `simultaneous` flag or xreplace instead of subs give the same result (on sympy.live.org). Then I tried to do the substitutions in reversed order, passing them as a list with the matrices first. Still didn't work. It looks like subs assumes that `0*foo` is 0. An issue at [sympy issues](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues) should be raised if there is not already an existing issue.

The workaround is to do the scalar substitutions first, allowing the zero terms to disappear. Then do a subs with the matrices. So this will require 2 calls to subs.

A true, hackish workaround for doing substitution with 0 is this:

```
def remul(m):
  rv = 1
  for i in m.args:
    rv *= i
  return rv

expr = x*y
mat = expr.subs(x, randMatrix(2)) # replace x with matrix
expr = mat.replace( # replace y with scalar 0
    lambda m: m.is_Mul,
    lambda m: remul(Mul(*[i.subs(y, 0) for i in m.args], evaluate=False)))
```

Comment: The issue doesn't seem to be restricted to 0... here is a minimal example that throws the same error the OP described in SymPy 1.1.1: `x,y=symbols('x y')` then `(x+y).subs({x: Matrix([1,2]), y: Matrix([3,4])})`

Comment: I get a different error on sympy.live.org but will investigate with the current version and report back. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The errors are both related to problems in the flattening routines for Mul (@32882 's issue) and Add (@Michelle 's). I have opened a PR that fixes these issues. The substitution is still order dependent, however, so if (after the fix) you want to keep the result as a matrix, you will need to use `simultaneous=True`. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/13279

Comment: So for a non-sympy developer do we have a simple resolution to this problem? This is a straightforward case of scalar times vector....

Comment: Have you downloaded the most recent version of SymPy and given this a try?